# Why was this question put on hold as off-topic? ("Has any country exempted their citizens/residents from the US citizenship-based taxation? ")

Tags: discussion, off-topic, closing-questions

The question [Has any country exempted their citizens/residents from the US citizenship-based taxation?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/97133/5656) was  put on hold as off-topic. Why?

From my understanding, this question is about personal finance as knowing which country exempted their citizens/residents from the US citizenship-based taxation directly applies to the OP's financial situation as a US citizen, which the OP intend to keep for work purposes, and as a citizen of another country, which  the OP is willing to switch if it is tax advantageous.

None of the close voters left the comment explaining their votes, and my comment asking them to explain their votes was removed, hence this question on meta.

I have no issue moving the question to another Stack Exchange but would like to understand better the scope of https://money.meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: And why was it put as off-topic due to *economics*?  There is no economics question here.  It might be Too Broad (any country).  It might not be personal finance, but it certainly isn't about economics.

Comment: When the question was voted to close, it was generic trying to find something. No clear distinction was made. It looked like wanting to know cause and effect and hence closed as Economics. The question was edited and the "intent" added after the question was closed to point out the personal finance aspect. This would still be quite broad, there may be some country; plus its ability to influence the US tax laws would be limited.

Comment: @Dheer thanks, the intent was added after the first close vote, even though it's really quite obvious to me (when someone looks for tax exemption, it's typically to pay less taxes). Regarding broadness, I could post one question for each country, but thought it'd be neater to have one unique question on it, as some answers could cover several countries at once (which is the case for the two answers posted so far).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Fair Points. It up for reopening, hopefully it will get enough votes. No raising 200 questions or if we take dozens of other countries that allow dual citizenship ... may be 5000 question ... doesn't make sense. In my view this is more of a Black Swan question. Intuitively I can say such an arrangement doesn't exist. Authoritatively I can't because I haven't studied laws for 200+ countries; if something like this existed, it would be all over front page of every finance and tax websites ... continued

Comment: there could still be some obscure treaty that is only applicable to handful of American Citizens ... and you may be eligible ... going by the up votes; its very popular question, people want to know if there are ways to retain US Citizenship for all the benefits and not pay taxes. However such thing doesn't exist and can anyone authoritatively prove it; probably not. Hence broad in my view.